# GitLab omnibus Sidekiq refusing to start due to missing Gemfile (8.11)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

A few days ago, one of my servers that was hosting a community edition of Gitlab rebooted (because of a hosting provider maintenance). Since that moment, that GitLab instance is partially broken : sidekiq completely refuses to start.

It restarts in an endless loop, with the following trace in the logs (from `gitlac-ctl tail`):

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/ci-sidekiq/current <==
2016-08-29_11:07:56.79639 bundler: failed to load command: sidekiq (/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sidekiq)
2016-08-29_11:07:56.79654 Bundler::GemfileNotFound: /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-ci/Gemfile not found
2016-08-29_11:07:56.79655   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:23:in `build'
2016-08-29_11:07:56.79655   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:123:in `definition'
2016-08-29_11:07:56.79655   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:91:in `setup'
2016-08-29_11:07:56.79656   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
2016-08-29_11:07:56.79656   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
2016-08-29_11:07:56.79656   /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

The problem occured on GitLab 8.5 (If I remember properly). I tried to uninstall the Omnibus package and update to the latest version (8.11), but it did not fixed the problem.

I checked by hand, the reported file (`/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-ci/Gemfile`) do not exists. Running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` also did not fixed the problem.

I'm really not familiar with Ruby ecosystem, so I'm asking for your help. Have you any idea how I can tackle this issue ? (I can provide more logs / informations if you think something relevant is missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the answer was but as I was in a hurry, I switched to a the [docker installation of GitLab](http://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/) which solved the problem (as well as bringing more isolation in my setup).

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted so that this question goes as solved. The system is totally ok with self accepted answers.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier sure, I was reluctant to do so since the problem itself is not really solved (I justed used a completely deployment method to avoid it), but it's done now :)